# Append a Command to the file in Unix

Tags: unix, ssh

how do we append a command to the first line of the file?
for example a command to display date?Thank in advance for your answer

Comment: Could you please clarify this question?  It seems confused-- what is 'appending a command to a line of a file'?  Also, what does the [ssh] tag have to do with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to prepend directly to a file without overwriting the file.

This may work for you instead.

```
mv file1.txt file1.txt.tmp       # Move file temporarily
date > file1.txt                 # Add your command
cat file1.txt.tmp >> file1.txt   # Append original content
rm file1.txt.tmp                 # Remove temporary file
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "not possible" as I'm fairly certain it can be done with `sed`. Your solution would work perfect on single files, a bit clunky for multiple files though.

Comment: @TheCapn: I've rephrased to be more precise

Comment: how to specify with `sed` that this is a command,not just character string?

Comment: @AdilliAdil I'm sorry I don't understand what you're looking for, you'll have to rephrase that.